# Jenkins bash scripts in temp folder not executing

Tags: shell, jenkins, containers, putty

I have a simple code as script file

```
#!/bin/bash
name1=$1
name2=$2
echo " $name1 $name2"
```

when i run in putty connected to the centos system inside the jenkins contained, it is giving output.
But when i try it through jenkins build, It is saying failure as the file is not found.

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/my_first_job
[my_first_job] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5284289512384758361.sh
+ Name=Madan
+ /tmp/1.sh Madan
/tmp/jenkins5284289512384758361.sh: 3: /tmp/jenkins5284289512384758361.sh: /tmp/1.sh: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is the error.

Comment: I am not able to get your set up. I hope by container you mean Docker container. If so, are you running Jenkins _as a_ Docker container or are you trying to run a Docker container _using_ Jenkins? In what scenario is your script working exactly?

Comment: Working when i run inside the docker directly..

Comment: When i execute build it fails

Comment: Is the script part of the Docker container that you're running? Please paste the `Dockerfile` content (except for the sensitive data, if any)